# Convert JWS to JSON using Volley throwing 400 response code error

Tags: android, json, safetynet

I am trying to use the `SafetyNet` API by google. I have successfully sent a request to the google server and got the JWS output. In order to parse the JWS to JSON I am sending the JWS token to a URL given by google. But for some reason it is showing some error.

Docs : [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html#verify-compat-check)

My Volley Code:

```
public void decodeJWS(final String x){
        String URL =  "https://www.googleapis.com/androidcheck/v1/attestations/verify?key="+getResources().getString(R.string.APIKey);
        StringRequest sq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                result.setText(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                result.setText(error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                headers.put("signedAttestation",x);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> body = new HashMap<>();
                body.put("signedAttestation",x);
                return body;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(sq);
    }
```

The error message says  `com.android.volley.serverError`.

The log says `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/androidcheck/v1/attestations/verify?key=MyKey`

I tried using `Postman` to send the same request but it gave me

```
{
  "isValidSignature": false
}
```

as the response. I believe I have set all the headers and stuff correctly in my volley code. Is there any error in that?

EDIT :

I updated my code to use `JSONObjectRequest`. When I use that there is no 400 error code but it is returning the same thing the Postman query returned.

```
 {
      "isValidSignature": false
    }
```

I am getting the signature from the `attestationResult` using the `getJWSResult()` call and then immediately sending it as a parameter to the function. Why is it then showing it is not a valid signature.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `getJwsResult()`?